# Sticky bit semantics on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Unix filesystems provide a sticky bit. When a directory is set world writable and has the sticky bit set, any user can create files in that directory. However, they can only delete or modify the files which they created, not those of other users.

Is there any way to achieve something like this in Amazon S3?

I would like to have two users which are allowed to create files in the same directory in the same bucket, but which are not allowed to change files which the other user created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't set such permissions. The only actions you can define (related to delete) in S3 are:

```
s3:GetObject
s3:GetObjectVersion
s3:DeleteObject
s3:DeleteObjectVersion
```